# Number of pendant vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple connected graph with only one cycle

If $G$ has four vertices of degree $2$, five vertices of degree $3$, three vertices of degree $4$, one vertex of degree $5$, how many pendant vertices does $G$ have if $\Delta = \text{max}\{\text{deg}(v)|v\in V\} = 5$?

My approach was to take the unique cycle (not necessarily on $6$ vertices like below) and open it:

[image]

to then get a tree.

We are essentially dividing a vertex in two, thus there are $|V|=4+5+3+1+\color{red}{1}+p=14+p$ vertices, where $p$ is how many pendant vertices there are in the original graph.

As per the edges $\sum\limits_{v \in V} \text{deg}(v) = 4\cdot 2 + 5\cdot 3 + 3\cdot 4 + 1\cdot 5 \color{red}{-1 +1} +p= 40+p=2|E|$

Then since we are working with a tree $2|V|=2|E|+2$, and $28+2p=40+p+2$, $p=14$.

I could be wrong though, I do not feel confident about my approach. How does one go about working this problem?

Comment: It looks perfectly fine to me (I would say it is clever to open a cycle to get a tree actually).

Comment: @ArsenBerk Thank you, and thank you for responding! I made some edits, adding in color to some numbers, since the cycle is unique, there can be no interior edges in the cycle and all the other components must be trees right? I was also curious about my calculations, are the 1's in red correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Actually I have written an answer as well but since I thought I did not add much to your solution, I deleted my answer. I may undelete it now since it does not involve with $+1-1$ idea but uses it to conclude a different result, which also ends up with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is perfectly fine (I would say it is clever actually). With the very same argument, one can show that if a simple connected graph $G$ has exactly one cycle, then $|V(G)| = |E(G)|$ (because when we open a cycle and get a tree, we increment the number of vertices by $1$ while keeping the number of edges same). Having said that, we can write

$$\sum\limits_{v \in V(G)}d(v) = 4\cdot 2 + 5\cdot 3 + 3\cdot 4 + 1\cdot 5 +p= 40+p=2|E(G)|=2|V(G)|$$

Then, since $|V(G)| = 4+5+3+1+p = 13+p$, we get $40+p = 2(13+p) \implies p = 14$ as you suggested. But as I said, the result $|V(G)| = |E(G)|$ when $G$ has only one cycle uses the very same argument that you used to find your result directly, so I am not adding much to your solution.

Comment: Actually this clears everything up, thank you very much for undeleting your answer, because I found it very ugly with the +1-1 and having to remember to add an extra vertex to $|V|$, this makes the calculation much nicer, easier, and there's no having to keep track of two graphs.